# Error : Transaction not successfully started Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, nullpointerexception

Ok guys, I know this question has been asked before. But the difference here is **I am not saving any object**. The idea is to let a student sign up only when parent has initiated a session (logged in). I have 4 entities:

- Student
- Parent
- Teacher
- User

All teacher, student and parent have a user_id. Student must always have a parent_id. When parent logs in, the parent id is saved and when student tries to sign up, it simply does not find the parent and NPE is thrown in stacktrace. But when UserAction runs by main(), it shows the ID perfectly.

Code UserAction.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.newidea.tottracker.action;

import com.newidea.tottracker.data.Roles;
import com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.Parent;
import com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.Student;
import com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.Teacher;
import com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.User;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
/**
 *
 * @author Mohit
 */
public class UserAction extends BaseAction{

    public UserAction(){}

    public int addUser(User user){
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = null;
        int id = 0;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            id = (Integer) session.save(user);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return id;
    }

    public User getUser(int id){
        User user;
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
            if(!tx.wasCommitted())tx.commit();
            System.out.println("Returning user ID : " + user.getId());
            return user;
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

            session.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Returning user ID : null");
        return null;
    }

    public User getUserByDetails(int role, String email){
        try{
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class);
            c.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
            c.add(Restrictions.eq("role", getRole(role)));
            if(c.list().isEmpty()) return null;
            else return (User) c.list().get(0);
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            if(session.isOpen()) session.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public User getUserByEmail(String email){
        try{
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class);
            c.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
            if(c.list().isEmpty()) return null;
            else return (User) c.list().get(0);
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            if(session.isOpen()) session.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getPersonIdByUserId(int userid, int role){
        try{
            System.out.println("Starting to fetch Person Type");
                    session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
//            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria c = null;
            switch(role){
                case Roles.STUDENT:
                    c = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
                    break;
                case Roles.PARENT:
                    c = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
                    break;
                case Roles.TEACHER:
                    c = session.createCriteria(Teacher.class);
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("Fetch User ID and Set to criteria");
                    c.add(Restrictions.eq("user", getUser(userid)));
            System.out.println("Criteria set successfully!");
                    switch(role){
                case Roles.STUDENT:
                    System.out.println("Returning Student User ID : " + userid);
                    Student student = (Student) c.list().get(0);
                    return student.getId();
                case Roles.PARENT:
                    System.out.println("Returning Parent User ID : " + userid);
                    Parent parent = (Parent) c.list().get(0);
                    return parent.getId();
                case Roles.TEACHER:
                    System.out.println("Returning Teacher User ID : " + userid);
                    Teacher teacher = (Teacher) c.list().get(0);
                    return teacher.getId();
            }
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
//            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
        }finally{
//            tx.commit();
            if(session.isOpen()) session.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean deleteUser(int id){
        User user;
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
            session.delete(user);
            tx.commit();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean updateUser(int id, User newUser){
        User user;
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
            user.setUsername(newUser.getUsername());
            user.setAnswer(newUser.getAnswer());
            user.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(newUser.getPassword());
            user.setRole(newUser.getRole());
            user.setSecurityQuestion(newUser.getSecurityQuestion());
            session.merge(user);
            tx.commit();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("User ID : 4\nRole ID : 1\nPerson Enitity ID : " + new UserAction().getPersonIdByUserId(4,1));
        System.out.println("User ID : 4\nRole ID : 1\nPerson Enitity ID : " + new UserAction().getPersonIdByUserId(4,1));
        System.out.println("User ID : 4\nRole ID : 1\nPerson Enitity ID : " + new UserAction().getPersonIdByUserId(4,1));
        System.out.println("User ID : 4\nRole ID : 1\nPerson Enitity ID : " + new UserAction().getPersonIdByUserId(4,1));

    }

}
```

AddStudent.jsp    //Page which causes the error

```
 <%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.ParentProfileId"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.ParentProfile"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.action.Views"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.action.AddressAction"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.Address"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.action.ParentAction"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.action.UserAction"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.data.Roles"%>
<%@page import="com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.Parent"%>
<%@page import="java.time.LocalDateTime"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@include file="header.jsp"%>
<%    Object roleObj = session.getAttribute("role");
    Object idObj = session.getAttribute("uid");
    int role, uid;
    Views profileDB = new Views();
    ParentProfileId profile;
    System.out.println(1);
    if (roleObj == null || idObj == null || !(Integer.parseInt(roleObj.toString()) == Roles.PARENT)) {
        roleObj = 0;

    System.out.println("In null value block");
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?code=1");
        return;
    } else {
        role = Integer.parseInt(roleObj.toString());
        uid = Integer.parseInt(idObj.toString());
        System.out.println("In not null value block");
//        System.out.println("Role : " + role + " UID : " + new UserAction().getPersonIdByUserId(uid, role));
        int parent_id = new UserAction().getPersonIdByUserId(uid, role);
        System.out.println("Parent ID : " + parent_id);
        profile = profileDB.getParentProfile(parent_id);

    }
%>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <form class="border" action="addStudent" method="post" style="">
                <center><h2 style="color: whitesmoke; ">Add your Child</h2><hr style="margin:0px" /></center>
                <div style="z-index: 100; background: whitesmoke">
                    <h3 style="font-size: 23px; padding: 15px;padding-bottom: 5px; margin: 0px">Personal Details</h3><center><hr style="margin:1px; height: 1px; background: lightgray; width: 96%" /></center>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">First Name</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Last Name</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="<%out.print(profile.getId());%>"/>
                        <label for="">Parent`s Name</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Parent`s Name" value="<%out.print(profile.getFirstName() + " " + profile.getLastName());%>" readonly="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">DOB</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" required="true" name="dob" max="<%out.print((LocalDateTime.now().getYear() - 18) + "-01-01");%>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Gender</label><req>*</req><br/>
                        <select name="gender" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Male</option>
                            <option value="1">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <h3 style="font-size: 23px; padding: 15px;padding-bottom: 5px; margin: 0px">Contact Information</h3><center><hr style="margin:1px; height: 1px; background: lightgray; width: 96%" /></center>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Phone Number</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" required="true" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="adderss">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="">Address</label><req>*</req>
                            <span  style="position: absolute; right: 0px;" id="sameAddr">
                                <input type="hidden" name="same_address" value="0"/>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="same_address" id="sameAddress" value="1"><label for="sameAddress">&nbsp;I live with my parent.</label>
                            </span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="address_id" value="<%out.print(profile.getAddressId());%>"/>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="address1" value="<%out.print(profile.getAddress1());%>" placeholder="Address Line 1"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address2" value="<%out.print(profile.getAddress2());%>" placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="city" value="<%out.print(profile.getCity());%>" placeholder="City"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="state" value="<%out.print(profile.getState());%>" placeholder="State"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="country_id" value="<%out.print(profile.getCountryId());%>"/>
                            <%@include file="countrylistselect.jsp" %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" required="true" name="pincode" value="<%out.print(profile.getPincode());%>" placeholder="Pincode"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Joining Date</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" required="true" name="doj" value="<%out.print(LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate());%>" />
                    </div>
                    <h3 style="font-size: 23px; padding: 15px;padding-bottom: 5px; margin: 0px">Login and Password Recovery Details</h3><center><hr style="margin:1px; height: 1px; background: lightgray; width: 96%" /></center>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Email</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Password</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" required="true" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Confirm Password</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" required="true" name="pass2" placeholder="Re-type Password"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Security Question</label><req>*</req>&nbsp;&nbsp;(In case you forget your password, answer this)
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="security_question" placeholder="Security Question" value="Mother`s Maiden Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="">Your Answer</label><req>*</req>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="answer" placeholder="Your Answer"/>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="accept-eula" id="eula"/> <label for="eula">By checking this box, I agree to <a href="#">all terms</a> to use TotTracker<sup>TM</sup></label><br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-bottom: 10px"/>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <script>
        $().ready(function() {
//            alert(("#sameAddress").val);
            $("#sameAddress").change(function() {
                if ($("#sameAddress").is(":checked")) {
//                    alert("Child has same address!");
                    $("input[name=address1]").val("<%out.print(profile.getAddress1());%>").change();
                    $("input[name=address2]").val("<%out.print(profile.getAddress2());%>").change();
                    $("input[name=city]").val("<%out.print(profile.getCity());%>").change();
                    $("input[name=state]").val("<%out.print(profile.getState());%>").change();
                    $("input[name=pincode]").val("<%out.print(profile.getPincode());%>").change();
                    $("#country").val("<%out.print(profile.getCountryIso());%>").change();
                    $("input[name=address1]").attr("readonly", true);
                    $("input[name=address2]").attr("readonly", true);
                    $("input[name=city]").attr("readonly", true);
                    $("input[name=state]").attr("readonly", true);
                    $("input[name=pincode]").attr("readonly", true);
                    $("#country").attr("readonly", true);
                    $("input[name=address1]").removeAttr("required");
                    $("input[name=address2]").removeAttr("required");
                    $("input[name=city]").removeAttr("required");
                    $("input[name=state]").removeAttr("required");
                    $("input[name=pincode]").removeAttr("required");

                } else {
//                     alert("Child dont have same address!");
                    $("input[name=address1]").removeAttr("readonly");
                    $("input[name=address2]").removeAttr("readonly");
                    $("input[name=city]").removeAttr("readonly");
                    $("input[name=state]").removeAttr("readonly");
                    $("input[name=pincode]").removeAttr("readonly");
                    $("#country").removeAttr("readonly");
                    $("input[name=address1]").attr("required", true);
                    $("input[name=address2]").attr("required", true);
                    $("input[name=city]").attr("required", true);
                    $("input[name=state]").attr("required", true);
                    $("input[name=pincode]").attr("required", true);
                    $("#country").attr("required", true);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

StackTrace:

```
    22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.694 SEVERE [41] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/TotTrack] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /AddStudent.jsp at line 52

49:                         <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
50:                     </div>
51:                     <div class="input-group">
52:                         <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="<%out.print(profile.getId());%>"/>
53:                         <label for="">Parent`s Name</label><req>*</req>
54:                         <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Parent`s Name" value="<%out.print(profile.getFirstName() + " " + profile.getLastName());%>" readonly="true"/>
55:                     </div>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.AddStudent_jsp._jspService(AddStudent_jsp.java:297)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Server Log:

```
1
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.170 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
In not null value block
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.462 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/newidea/tottracker/mappings/StudentProfile.hbm.xml
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.474 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/newidea/tottracker/mappings/ExamResult.hbm.xml
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.490 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.494 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.494 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.494 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.494 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.494 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.550 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.570 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
22-Mar-2016 16:56:05.570 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.<init> HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Starting to fetch Person Type
Fetch User ID and Set to criteria
Error : Transaction not successfully started
Parent ID : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, the error was in the values that were being passed. I was calling `getPersonIdByUserId` firstly on the authenticate servlet and then again on the page which was causing the real pain. For anybody else it may be helpful.